# What bad thing do "sort" and "uniq" do to the authorized_keys file?

Tags: ssh, login, sort, uniq

I tried something that seemed to me like it should have worked. I had a bunch of public ssh keys I wanted to import, so I did this.

```
cat public_ssh_keys .ssh/authorized_keys | sort | uniq > AK
mv AK .ssh/authorized_keys
```

This was on an EC2 instance, and suddenly I couldn't log in any more. I haven't tried to research this, just wondering if anybody knows off the top of their head what would fail here?

Comment: I am not sure how `sort` and `uniq` would treat that sort of input, but I believe it may be a permissions issue.  I believe OpenSSH will error if some of the files have permissions that are too laxed.  When you moved `AK` in place of `.ssh/authorized_keys` that file will now have the permissions that `AK` had.

Comment: were you in your home directory? Otherwise the relative path of `.ssh/authorized_keys` wouldn't find the file. I'd hope you would inspect `AK` before using it.

Comment: A couple years later so my memory is not perfect, but one thing I failed to mention was that the instance was probably running SELinux-hardened CentOS. SELinux has something called contexts which can get in a bad state where `authorized_keys` stops working. The fix for it is `restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh`. Something I learned later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your default `umask` is something like `0002`, then `AK` and hence the new `.ssh/authorized_keys` would be created with write permission for the owning group. `sshd` doesn't like that since that might allow some other user to modify the file and log in under your account. What the umask is by default, depends on the system.

(If someone actually can do that depends on if any other users are members of the same group, and what the permissions of your home directory and `~/.ssh` are, but it doesn't bother checking that far.)

For `authorized_keys`, read access by others isn't something the server cares about: it only contains the public parts of the keys, and they're not really that sensitive.

So, `ls -l .ssh/authorized_keys` to check the permissions, and then `chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys` (or such), if there's too much access.

`sort` and `uniq` shouldn't do anything bad to the file, it only contains lines of text, and their order doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks! I am pretty sure it's a permissions issue. My reason for "sort | uniq" was just to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Indeed, it did turn out that the permissions on the "authorized_keys" file needs to be 600, which my original commands would not accomplish.